# Webrtc: Could not process WebRTC answer

Tags: node.js, xmpp, webrtc, jingle, stanza.io

Im using ejabberd + stanza io to build a realtime messaging and audio calling website.
ive managed to make my first audio call

```
from chrome(on PC) -> chrome(on mac) with no errors
```

the problem occurs when i try to make the call

```
from chrome(on mac) to firefox(on pc) or vice versa
```

the chrome browser log is showing 
`Could not process WebRTC answer`

by using the `chrome://webrtc-internals` debugger tool ive figured out that `setremotedescription` failed with the error:

```
`Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called with SDP without ice-ufrag and ice-pwd`
```

this is what im using to start a call:

```
var session = client.jingle.createMediaSession('full JID');
  session.addStream(localAudio_stream); // getUserMedia stream
  session.start();
```

what am i doing wrong? how can firefox successfully establish a call but chrome cant (tested on opera to with the same result (failure))

[Full JS code](https://pastebin.com/TfXpEjtK)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i've solved the problem by including the npm package sdpparser in the client.js (of stanza.io) then building it again, and in stanza.io.bundle ive tweaked the `PeerConnection.prototype.handleAnswer` like so:

```
var sdp = client.SdpParser.parse(answer.sdp);
sdp.media.forEach(function(media){
  if(media.type === 'video' && media.inactive ) {
    delete media.fingerprint;
    media.port = 0;
  }
});
answer.sdp = client.SdpParser.format(sdp);
```

this may not be the best way to do it , but it definitely solves the problem.

[github link of the tweaked stanza.io](https://github.com/medabida/staza.io-jingle/tree/master)

[Helpful github issue on jingle.js repo](https://github.com/otalk/jingle.js/issues/24)